# Xcode - "The file couldn't be opened"

Tags: xcode, react-native

Workspace gets opened in Xcode(14.2) but when I click on the project I get "The file couldn't be opened" alert. Also, the run and build button is disabled. What could be the possible issue ?

I've tried multiple solutions for this issue as mentioned below but none of them worked

- Cleared the derived data, restarted the mac and Xcode as well
- Deleted pods and re-installed again
- Opened package contents of .xcworkspace and deleted content inside xcuserdata
- Changed the version of Xcode from 14.3.1 to 14.2
- Opened the project from Xcode window as well

[Screenshot of Xcode with project open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx7dv.png)